# What graphics cards can I use for Windows 7 Phone development?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I downloaded the new SDK (7.1) for Windows Phone 7 development. When I try to run a Silverlight application I get a message telling me my graphics card isn't supported so the experience is downgraded. I can't run XNA programs at all.

I have a GeForce 6600 family card, which I thought would be good enough but I guess not. Can anyone tell me some graphics cards that are suitable that are also inexpensive and will support dual monitors at 1920*1280?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or later graphics card with WDDM 1.1 driver. AFAIK the latest certified drivers (certainly for Windows 7) for the GeForce 6600 family of graphics cards fit these requirements, so you may just need to update your drivers.

Comment: I'm not sure what WDDM1.1 is but I am running DirectX11 with the card. I'll take a trip to the web site and download the latest drivers to try out.

Comment: No joy with the latest card drivers. From what I read on the nvidia site they are WDDM 1.0. Either way, I still can't run XNA and still get the message about lowered experience quality on Silverlight apps.

Comment: ...and I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: If you run DxDiag and look at the Display tabs, it will tell you which version of WDDM you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the newest graphic card drivers installed? I can run XNA games (tested with a Windows phone) on a Intel onboard graphics (Intel HD3200 I think).

If the driver doesn't help choose from a current card or the previous generation. How much many do you want to spend?

Comment: Not much :) Most of my code is WPF for non-web and Silverlight / ASP.NET for web stuff. The phone development was an idea I had for having a bit of fun so don't want to end up spending hundreds of dollars.

Comment: A graphics card around $100 should be enough. Look after somethng like Radeon 6570 or 6670. You get the newest stuff (DirectX 11 etc) and get 3 display connectors.